# Error while resolving instance for class 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient' - Can't create definition for 'Single'

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin, koin-scope

I am getting below error after merging my code from separate local branch to 'development' branch:

> Error while resolving instance for class 'okhttp3.OkHttpClient' - error: org.koin.error.BeanInstanceCreationException: Can't create definition for 'Single [name='OkHttpClient',class='okhttp3.OkHttpClient']' due to error :
> null

It's Working fine in my local branch. I am not getting error in that local separate branch.

To Use the Koin library I have done below code in my Application class :

```
private fun initializeKoin() {
    startKoin(this, listOf(appViewModelModule, appModule, appNetworkModule, databaseModule))
}
```

The Issue is the above error I am getting while running the application.
What might causing the issue?

Comment: Add a  code of module network. I guess problem in initialisation a client for koin graph.

Comment: your question incomplete to answer . Add the module file with question where you are building the dependencies .

Comment: Add a code of appNetworkModule where actually you are using single.